# Spark Streaming get one element per key in PairDStream

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Simple question: any actually efficient way to get a dstream made of one key-value pair per key? pseudocode:

```
myKeyValueDStream = {(A,miao-1-3),
(A,miao-2-4),
(A,miao-5-6),
(B,bau-1-2),
(B,bau-3-4),
(C,cip-1-2),
(C,cip-3-4)}
singleLineDStream = myKeyValueDStream.takeOneElementPerKey();
//I don't care which one; the first one would be fine
singleLineDStream.print() // {(A,miao-1-3),(B,bau-1-2),(C,cip-1-2)}
```

my solution as of now (apologies for Java 7):

```
JavaPairDstream<String,String[]> singleLineDStream = pairdDstream.reduceByKey(new Function2<String[],String[],String[]>(){
        @Override
        public String[] call(String[] arg0, String[] arg1) throws Exception {
            return arg0;
        }
    });
```

Is there a better way to take one element for each key? Use whatever language you want for the solution.

Comment: `reduceByKey` should be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will trust maasg and say that indeed, I gave the answer in my question:

```
JavaPairDstream<String,String[]> singleLineDStream = pairdDstream.reduceByKey(new Function2<String[],String[],String[]>(){
    @Override
    public String[] call(String[] arg0, String[] arg1) throws Exception {
        return arg0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing can be done is to use the **CollectAsMap** function over the RDD to use it as a Dictionary containing one value for each key in the set. After that, the dictionary can be converted into list with key-value pairs.

As in this [Pyspark Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n5eb.jpg)

Comment: that would require that all the data in the dstream is collected at the driver, with two consequences: 1) unnecessary network overhead; 2) the driver might not have enough memory to hold all data. If there's a way to keep the collection distributed, it should be preferred.